# How to theme my website with cake php?

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, themes, cakephp-1.3

I need some help to theme my website a test project to learn cakephp 1.3.4. I have created files for these like  default.ctp for website default layout. and home.ctp for home page layout, I try Google for help but there I found nothing a good tutorial for a beginner to help me understand how to use any theme or layout for cakephp website.

Can some give a reference link to any material that helps me to understand what exactly I have had to do with cakephp design techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this: [Themes in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/view/488/Themes) overall site book.cakephp.com is the best resource for learning CakePHP

Comment: thanks Nik. It has a very useful information but not enough. I'll try to find some more and surely with share all community members.

Comment: maybe if you explain some more concrete problem we can help you better

Comment: oh sure. actually I am trying to make a cms system. A public site and an admin site. I used cakephp 1.3.4 to bake all models, controllers and views for tables and all my relations are well defined. I am stuck how do I can theme both of sites the admin area and the public area. I have created some elements reuseable like header footer and some side bars. But I want to know how Do I have to handle the content of main container based on the request